# Netbeans Installation cannot find JRE

Tags: netbeans, installation, environment-variables, command-prompt, java-6

I am trying to install Netbeans 8.2 on my Microsoft surface pro and I am using JDK 10.0.2. When I run the Netbeans installer it is unable to find the JDK. So I used the --javahome command with the correct file destination and I suppose it finds the JDK. But then it throws the same error for the JRE. I do not know why the JRE cannot be found. I have been reading many similar questions and am seeing directions saying to use JAVA_HOME and set the environment variables. I am very unfamiliar with the windows command prompt, so I would appreciate a more specific solution.

Comment: I don't think NetBeans 8.2 supports Java 10, you need to use Apache NetBeans 9.0

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know, JDK doesn't come with JRE, so check in your Java folder if you got JRE installed, if not, try downloading it manually.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.2 of NetBeans does not support JDK 10.

However, ownership of NetBeans has recently been moved from Oracle to Apache and you can use JDK 10 with [NetBeans 9.0 RC1](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html) (RC = "Release Candidate").

Just download the zip file, unzip it and then locate and run **netbeans64.exe** (or **netbeans.exe** for 32-bit) within the unzipped folder. Those steps are the same regardless of operating system.

When NetBeans starts it should automatically locate your installed JDKs, but verify that you have JDK 10 included as a Java Platform from the **Tools > Java Platforms** screen:

[image: Java platforms]

You can explicitly add JDK 10 to NetBeans if necessary:

- **Tools > Java Platforms**
- Click **Add Platform** and complete the wizard to add JDK 10.

Once you have JDK 10 included in **Java Platforms** you can create a trivial Java 10 project, although the process is not completely intuitive:

- **File >  New Project > Java > Java Application**
- Accept all the default options. A new project with a name of the form *JavaApplication{n}* will be created.
- In the **Projects** panel select the project's node, right click and select **Properties** from the popup menu.
- Select **Libraries** from the list of **Categories** and set **Java Platform** to **JDK 10**.
- Select **Sources** from the list of **Categories**, set **Source/Binary Format** to **JDK 10** and click **OK**.

You now have a Java 10 project. To verify that, make sure that the following code compiles as your `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var v = 7;
}
```